# Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target

Tags: shell-script

Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

Example:
Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1].

Trying this out in bash, but mine fails with syntax errors, please let me know if the logic is right and if there's any syntax errors:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such 
# that they add up to a specific target.

read T
nums=("2" "7" "11" "15")

for i in ${nums[@]}
do
    for j in ${nums[@]}
    do
        if [ "$i" + "$j" == $T ]
            echo "i=$i"
            echo "j=$j"
            break
        fi
    done
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` needs a corresponding `then`, and you should<sup>1</sup> use `(( . . .))` for the arithmetic test, i.e.

```
if (( $i + $j == $T )); then
```

or since

> Within an expression, shell
>   variables may also be referenced by name without  using  the  parameter
>   expansion  syntax.

you can simplify that to

```
if (( i + j == T )); then
```

See the `SHELL GRAMMAR - Compound Commands` subsection of `man bash`.

---

1. You may see an older arithmetic evaluation syntax `$[ . . . ]`, making

   ```
   if [ $[$i + $j] == $T ]; then
   ```

   also legal - but this is deprecated and shouldn't be used in new scripts.

Comment: Why do you show deprecated syntax at all when `$(( ... ))` is standard?

Answer (score 0):

`for i in "${array[@]}"` loops over the *values* of the associative array¹. If, like here, you want to loop over the keys (indices), it's `for in "${!array[@]}"` in `bash`. So:

```
#! /bin/bash -
T=${1?Please pass a decimal integer number as argument}
nums=(2 7 11 15)
found=false

if [[ ! $T =~ ^-?[0123456789]+$ ]]; then
  printf >&2 '"%s" is not a valid integer number\n' "$T"
  exit 2
fi
  
for i in "${!nums[@]}"; do
  for j in "${!nums[@]}"; do
    if ((nums[i] + nums[j] == T)); then
      printf '%s\n' "i=$i nums[i]=${nums[i]}" "j=$j nums[j]=${nums[j]}"
      found=true
      break 2
    fi
  done
done
"$found"
```

Note that it's important to validate the input number passed as argument as otherwise, the code would introduce an arbitrary command execution vulnerability.

Also note that `bash` understands numbers with leading zeros as *octal* numbers, so 010 would be understood as 8, not 10.

---

<sup>¹ bash arrays, like in ksh are *sparse arrays*, so like associative arrays with keys limited to positive integers. Since version 4.0, bash also supports associative arrays with keys limited to sequences of **one** or more non-NUL bytes, declared with `declare -A`, and using the same `"${!assoc[@]}"` syntax to get the list of keys.</sup>